# Calculating mean and median of responses corresponding to unique users

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with userid, text responses and a few other variables. Some of the text responses are blank for an user. I would like to calculate mean number of responses/user, median number of responses/user and standard deviation of the mean. I would like to use base R functions or dplyr library for doing so. What is the best way for approaching this problem?

```
userid, text
1,      abc
1,  
1,      abcd
1,  
1,      asdf
1,      
2,      text2
2,      text3
3,      text4
3,      
3,      text5
```

For the mean, I just did `sum(df$text != '')/(length(unique(df$userid)))`
Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

The data structure that would be more sensible towards such mean, median & sd calculations is to recode the "" into NAs (if "" means *no answer* from respondent) so the data.frame would look like so:

```
data <- data.frame(userid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
                text = c("abc", NA, "abcd", NA, "asdf", NA, "text2", "text3", "text4", NA, "text5"))
```

This you can achieve by recoding "" into NAs like

```
df$text[df$text==""] <- NA
```

Then you could aggregate your data (base R):

```
aggregation <- aggregate(text~userid, data, length)
#  userid text
#1      1    3
#2      2    2
#3      3    2
```

and calculate the statistics

```
sapply(list(mean=mean , median=median, sd=sd), function(i) i(aggregation$text))
#     mean    median        sd 
#2.3333333 2.0000000 0.5773503
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering counting responses you should consider edge cases such as the response text being just a string of blanks which you would not want to count as a response. You should also guard against the possibility of the text response not being present at all in your data - potentially a NULL value in R, though you do not show any in your made-up data.

I'd also suggest using a step by step method which allows you to verify the counts before generating summary results if you want to see how many responses you had for instance.

A dplyr example:

```
library(dplyr)

group_by(df, userid) %>%
  summarise(nresponses = 
              sum(case_when(is.null(text) ~ 0, 
                            nchar(trimws(text))==0 ~ 0,
                            TRUE ~ 1  ))) %>%
  summarise(respondents = n(), 
            mean = mean(nresponses), 
            median = median(nresponses),
            sd = sd(nresponses))

# A tibble: 1 x 4
  respondents     mean median        sd
        <int>    <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
1           3 2.333333      2 0.5773503
```

If I execute to the first summarise statement for checking purposes you will see the intermediate counts that are then summarised in the second statement:

```
> group_by(df, userid) %>%
+   summarise(nresponses = 
+               sum(case_when(is.null(text) ~ 0, 
+                             nchar(trimws(text))==0 ~ 0,
+                             TRUE ~ 1  )))

    # A tibble: 3 x 2
      userid nresponses
       <int>      <dbl>
    1      1          3
    2      2          2
    3      3          2
```

In my view when you are working with real data rather than a few made-up lines it is essential to be able to work back and verify how you got your results.

Data from your question:

```
df = read.table(text = "userid, text
1,      abc
1,  
1,      abcd
1,  
1,      asdf
1,      
2,      text2
2,      text3
3,      text4
3,      
3,      text5", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ",")
```